# Вывести содержимое List из XML в переменную

Tags: c#, windows, .net, xml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне вывести в combobox содержимое `Username`?
Вот класс `User`

```
[Serializable]
public class Users
{
    public Users() { }
    public List<User> UsersList = new List<User>() { };
}

[Serializable]
public class User
{
    [XmlElement("USER")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string NukeCode { get; set; }
    public string AccRight { get; set; }

    public User() { }

    public User(string Username, string NukeCode, string AccRight)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.NukeCode = NukeCode;
        this.AccRight = AccRight;
    }
}
```

Вот десериализация:

```
private Users DeserializeXML()
{
    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("ValueTemp.ddl", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        return (Users)xml.Deserialize(fs);
    }
}
```

Нужно `Username` засунуть в переменную и вывести ее содержимое в combobox на форме. Пока что, я делаю это так:

```cs
foreach (User user in DeserializeXML().UsersList)
{
    cbMultiAuth.Items.Add(user.Username);
}
```

Но это, вроде как можно упростить. А как, я не понимаю.

Comment: в c# нет глобальных переменных и функций. переменные бывают только локальными, а то, в чём вы пишете исполняемый код, называется методом. перепишите свой вопрос, а то непонятно что, куда и зачем нужно "вывести".

Comment: Вроде переписал понятней...

Comment: зачем вы вызываете `DeserializeXML` перед циклом?

Comment: Да, действительно. В этом нет необходимости. Спасибо, за замечание.

Comment: уберите класс `Users`, он только мешает. вместо него используйте обычные коллекции. именуйте коллекции `users`, а не `usersList`. вы можете использовать `using var x = ...` вместо `using (var x = ...) {}`. не используйте венгерскую нотацию.

Comment: поля обычно именуются как `_name`, параметры метода/переменные — `name`, всё остальное — `SomeClassName`, например. и тогда не нужно `this` в том же конструкторе использовать

Comment: Что за комбобокс, из какого GUI? WinForms? Добавьте метку.

Comment: Здесь есть хороший пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600869/how-to-bind-a-list-to-a-combobox